# @param in Solidity comments

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, blockchain

In examples provided on the [Ethereum.org](https://www.ethereum.org/token#the-code) website, there are comments with `@param` that mention what the specific parameter is used for. **Why does it exist?**

Answer (score 1):

Solidity uses Doxygen-style commenting. The `@param` is used for explaining what the parameter does. Doxygen defines certain structure for writing comments so that the comments can be automatically exported into another document (for example some documentation of the code).

More info about Doxygen: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doxygen

Comment: Didn't know this was a thing. I would assume the spacing for the description matters as well. Does this work only with multi line comments?(I'm thinking some sort of Regex is used here)

Comment: I'm not really a Doxygen expert so you should just check their documentation. I have no idea hoe lenient / strict they are with the formats.